# Workspaces in overlay and keyboard disappeared in Ubuntu 14.04 / Gnome

Tags: 14.04, unity, gnome, workspaces, expo-mode

How can I reconfigure the workspaces in Ubuntu 14.04.3 with GNOME? Two days ago I was able to switch using keyboard shortcuts `CTRL` + `ALT` + `LEFT` OR `RIGHT` and drag and drop frames from the Expo into a separate workspace.

Now, despite being enabled in the Keyboard Shortcuts, switching to a new workspace does not work. In addition, the Expo has one workspace visible when set to Dynamics in:

> Tweak Tools > Workspaces > Workspace Creation

When above is set to Static the Number of Workspaces are shown, but they are exact replicas of the first one:
[see image of workspaces replicated when set to 4 static](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zg6NA.png)

So far, with no luck, I have rebooted, reinstalled Unity, enabled CompizConfig > Desktop Wall + Expo + Desktop Size (2x2), reinstall ubuntu-desktop, reinstall ubuntu-gnome-desktop^.

Comment: I have multiple GPUs, after changing to Intel HD Graphics the workspaces functionality returned. The Prime Indicator switch [link] (http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/prime-indicator-lets-you-quickly-switch.html), lets you change GPU easier. This is a problem with NVIDIA display graphics when using the proprietary NVIDIA binary driver v-352.63, in Software & Updates > Additional Drivers.